# Replace dollar + number with other string

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm trying to find substrings in a string and then replace them with other string.

The substring I'm looking for has $ + number format.

For example, `$1250`, `$512`, `$0`, etc..

I would like to detect these substrings from string and then replace them with other string.

**My Code :**

```
#include <iostream>

void replaceDollarNumber(std::string &str, std::string replace)
{
    size_t pos;
    while ((pos = str.find('$')) != std::string::npos)
    {
        size_t len = pos + 1;
        while (len < str.length() && isdigit(str[len]))
        {
            len++;
        }
        str.erase(pos, --len);
        str.insert(pos, replace);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "!$@#$34$1%^&$5*$1$!%$91$12@$3";
    replaceDollarNumber(str, "<>");
    std::cout << "Result : " << str << '\n';
}
```

**Result I expect :**

```
Result : !$@#<><>%^&<>*<>$!%<><>@<>
```

**Result I get :**

```
Result : !<>@#<>&<>91<>
```

How can I correct the `replaceDollarNumber` function so I can get the result I want?

Also, I would like to know if there's more performant solution.

**EDITED: I would also like to know how to do this without using regex**

Comment: Try using Regular Expressions to find and replace strings that match a certain pattern: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example with regexes, compile with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
std::string replaceDollarNumber(std::string str, std::string replace)
{
    std::regex long_word_regex("(\\$[0-9]+)");
    std::string new_s = std::regex_replace(str, long_word_regex, replace);
    return new_s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "!$@#$34$1%^&$5*$1$!%$91$12@$3";
    auto new_s = replaceDollarNumber(str, "<>");
    std::cout << "Result : " << new_s << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code has two problems. First, the second argument to `basic_string::erase` should be the **length** of the text to be erased; this function calls it with the index of the last character to be erased. Second, the code inserts the replacement text even if there were no digits found.

Fixing those two problems gives this:

```
void replaceDollarNumber(std::string &str, std::string replace)
{
    size_t pos;
    while ((pos = str.find('$')) != std::string::npos)
    {
        size_t end = pos + 1;
        while (end < str.length() && isdigit(str[end]))
        {
            end++;
        }
        if (end != pos + 1)
        {
            str.erase(pos, end - pos);
            str.insert(end, replace);
        }
    }
}
```

I've renamed `len` to `end` to better reflect its actual meaning.

I haven't tested the code; I think `end - pos` is correct, but it could be off by one.

Finally, I'd use `basic_string::replace` instead of `erase` and `insert`.